# How to compile Julia to executable (Windows machine)

Tags: compilation, julia, packagecompiler.jl

i have ran the below command and nothing works for me.

```
juliac.jl -vae compile=all C:\PackageCompiler\examples\hello.jl
```

Note:
installed `PackageCompiler.jl`

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you elaborate more kn what isn’t working?

Comment: No it doesn't throw error .but juts gets stuck.i am doing something wrong not getting whats wrong